# Laravel adding bcc in notification mail

Tags: php, laravel

I'm always getting an error in my notification email.
Any Idea how to support bcc in Laravel email notification?
I used Laravel 5.4.

Error:

```
Call to a member function bcc() on null
```

Codes:

```
$inquiry->notify(new SupportEmail("user@user.com",  $inquiry->email))->bcc("example@example.com", "admin@admin.com");
```

Answer (score 6):

The only way to add mail features such as cc, bcc and attachments, is to return a mailable object from the toMail() method of your notification.

```
public function toMail($notifiable){
  return (new Mailable())->to($notifiable->email)->bcc($this->bcc_array);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need some extra parentheses around the `new SupportEmail` declaration:

```
$email = new SupportEmail("user@user.com", $inquiry->email);
$email = $email->bcc("example@example.com", "admin@admin.com");
$inquiry->notify($email);
```

Comment: Because this is an old project.
what is the difference between my codes in your codes?

Comment: But it is probably running in production, since you have to send emails. You won't get (security) updates anymore, watch out for that. Updated my answer, you needed some extra parentheses.

Comment: Huh. Updated my answer, just for reference, does that work? If not, there's something weird going on with the email creation.

Comment: I get other error. 

Call to undefined method App\Notifications\Frontend\Inquiry\SupportEmail::bcc()

Comment: I think bcc is not supported in notification .

Comment: Apparently not, more people have this issue. One workaround is with using `Mailable`: https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/15694. Otherwise, this just isn't possible I guess.